# Not able to install 3rd party provider plugins

Tags: terraform, jenkins-pipeline, terraform-provider-kubernetes

Can someone please help on the below error:

```
Error: Failed to install provider

Error while installing gavinbunney/kubectl v1.14.0: could not query
provider registry for registry.terraform.io/gavinbunney/kubectl: failed to
retrieve authentication checksums for provider: the request failed after 2
 attempts, please try again later: Get
 "https://github.com/gavinbunney/terraform-provider-kubectl/releases/download/v1.14.0/terraform-provider-kubectl_1.14.0_SHA256SUMS":
 net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout
 exceeded while awaiting headers)


 Error: Failed to install provider
 
 Error while installing gavinbunney/bitbucketserver v1.7.1: could not query
 provider registry for registry.terraform.io/gavinbunney/bitbucketserver:
 failed to retrieve authentication checksums for provider: the request
failed after 2 attempts, please try again later: Get
 "https://github.com/gavinbunney/terraform-provider-bitbucketserver/releases/download/v1.7.1/terraform-provider-bitbucketserver_1.7.1_SHA256SUMS":
 net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout
 exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

---

My providers.tf file looks like below :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {

    bitbucketserver = {
      source  = "gavinbunney/bitbucketserver"
      version = "~> 1.5"
    }
    kubectl = {
      source  = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
      version = "~> 1.14.0"
    }
  }
}
```

---

I am trying to install the latest version of the providers.

Comment: This would appear to be a networking issue. Is it safe to assume you are behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: Correct. I have no problem in downloading and using releases by Hashicorp but I am not able to do the same for 3rd party signed plugins